# HTML Table Showing Headers Even When No Data Returned

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have this line in my syntax `if (query)` which I thought would check if the query was null, however my query returns 0 rows and the header row is still displayed.

What is the proper way to ensure the query returns rows before you display the table?

```
<?php
$option = array();
$option['driver'] = 'mssql';
$option['host'] = 'ServerName';
$option['user'] = 'username';
$option['password'] = 'password';
$option['database'] = 'database';
$option['prefix'] = '';
$db = JDatabase::getInstance($option);
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "SELECT blue, green, red, purple, pink from colors";
$db->setQuery($query);
$query = $db->loadObjectList();
if (query)
{
?>
<div id="dvData">
<table id="example" border="1">
    <caption><strong style="font-size:25px;"><?php echo $startdate ?> - <?php echo $enddate ?></strong></caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#00FF00">Blue </th>
        <th bgcolor="#00FF00">Green </th>
        <th bgcolor="#00FF00">Red </th>
        <th bgcolor="#00FF00">Purple </th>
        <th bgcolor="#00FF00">Pink </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
foreach ($query as $res) 
{
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>" . $res->Blue . "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $res->Green . "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $res->Red . "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $res->Purple . "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $res->Pink . "</td>";
    print "</tr>";
}
} 
?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `if (query)` a typo in your question here, or is that in your actual code?

Comment: If that's what you have in your code, it would explain the behavior. PHP would see an undefined constant and convert it to a string that would evaluate to true, I believe.

Comment: @Don'tPanic -> yes that is my actual code.

Comment: Well, put a `$` on it and try it again. :)

Comment: @Don'tPanic - aye-yay-yaye, that got it.  thank you